# What would be the problem if I update resource with POST request?

Tags: laravel, post, patch, put

It is a weird question but I have some problems with understanding this.
I now that Post is supposed to create a new resource and Put to edit this resource or create a new one if it does not exist.

But what will be the problem if I will do edit with Post request and logic in the controller will be for PUT?

Comment: Pretty much nothing, it's just an HTTP convention

Comment: so, this is just for the frontend to know what this HTTP does?